# Requesting and Parsing a JSON with Python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have this code below that I'm working on as part of an AI project. I'm looking to get tags that the user searches and return a url of a post with said tags.

```
from meya import Component
import requests
import json

API_URL = "https://e621.net/post/index.json?limit=1&tags=rating:s+order:random+{tag}"

class e621_call(Component):
"""Produces a e621 post based on the user's tags."""

def start(self):
    tag = self.properties.get('tag') or \
        self.db.flow.get('tag')

    response = requests.get(API_URL.format(tag=tag))

    img = response.json()['file_url']

    message = self.create_message(text=img)

    return self.respond(message=message, action="next")
```

Everything is fine up until I assign img to the *file_url* value, which brings up a

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

For the record, I am using meya.ai for this, and the packages are not the issue

Comment: The returned JSON data is a list, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API returns a dictionary inside a list. Get inside the list first then you can do what you wish with the dictionary.

```
response = requests.get(API_URL)
foo = json.loads(response.content)
file_url = foo[0].get('file_url')
```

If you plan on having multiple dictionaries returned inside the list, you can just loop through foo and find the multiple urls.

```
for d in foo:
    print d.get('file_url')
```

Also, I prefer to not use .json() (As you may have noticed I didn't include it in my answer) because that way you can correctly check for the status_code first before proceeding. Otherwise if you get a 404 or a 500 for example, you will get errors.

```
if response.status_code == 200:
    do stuff here
else:
    print "Something is wrong"
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a temporary workthrough, replacing `response.json()['file_url']` with `response.json()[0]['file_url']` works fine in the AI, although it still gives me the error.